# Ethernet and wifi not working Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: network-manager

Ethernet and wifi both are not working on ubuntu 16.04.

ifconfig command do not show any network except local loopback.

Tried to set wifi and ethernet manually as well but no success.

Please suggest ways to tackle with this issue.

Output for the Commands : lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'
and sudo lshw -c network  are : -

```
navneet@navneet-HP-Notebook:~$ lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:8135]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]

navneet@navneet-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo lshw -c network

[sudo] password for navneet:

  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1200000-a1200fff memory:a1000000-a1003fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a1103fff
```

Thanks

Navneet

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `sudo lshw -c network `.

Comment: I fixed this issue by reinstalling this driver from https://github.com/ghostrider-reborn/realtek-r8101-linux-driver

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the internet using your phone and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

That should fix the wireless.